# inspect.currentframe() may not work under some implementations?

Tags: python, python-3.x, stack, language-implementation

According to the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html?highlight=currentframe#inspect.currentframe):

> `inspect.currentframe()`
>
> Return the frame object for the caller’s stack
>   frame.
>
> CPython implementation detail: This function relies on Python stack
>   frame support in the interpreter, which isn’t guaranteed to exist in
>   all implementations of Python. If running in an implementation without
>   Python stack frame support this function returns None.

How is it that only this function is marked as "implementation-dependent"? If this function doesn't work, wouldn't similar functions, such as `inspect.trace`, `inspect.stack`, etc. also be unavailable?

Also, what does "stack frame support" mean, and why would it ever be absent?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The availability of `inspect.currentframe` is tied to `sys._getframe`:

```
def currentframe():
    """Return the frame of the caller or None if this is not possible."""
    return sys._getframe(1) if hasattr(sys, "_getframe") else None
```

The restriction thus applies to all other functions also using `sys._getframe`. For `inspect`, this is only `inspect.stack`.

In contrast, `inspect.trace` uses `sys.exc_info`. This is an integral part of exception handling schemes, and should always be available. All other related function, e.g. `getframeinfo`, already rely on there being a frame. Their applicability depends on whether you want to inspect an exception or call traceback.

Note that my local, default jython *does* support `sys._getframe`. ipy works if run with `-X:Frames`.

Answer (score 2):

The other implementations the docs refer to are Jython and IronPython. These are Python language implementations that run in a different VM (JVM and CLR) and don't have such a stack frame. I think IronPython has later added some support for that, however.

Comment: But how is it that just `inspect.currentframe` isn't supported, but `inspect.trace` and `inspect.stack` work fine? (That's what the docs imply.)

Comment: And what alternative of `inspect.currentframe()` can be for ironpython?