# setting imported functions as members in a static dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, python-import, python-object

There is a simple class where I want to store some functions statically in a dictionary using different ways:

```
import os, sys
class ClassTest():
    testFunc = {}
    def registerClassFunc(self,funcName):
        ClassTest.testFunc[funcName] = eval(funcName)
    @classmethod
    def registerClassFuncOnClass(cls,funcName):
        cls.testFunc[funcName] = eval(funcName)
    @staticmethod
    def registerClassFuncFromStatic(funcName):
        ClassTest.testFunc[funcName] = eval(funcName)
```

Some example methods:

```
def user_func():
    print("I run therefore I am self-consistent")
def user_func2():
    print("I am read therefore I am interpreted")
def user_func3():
    print("I am registered through a meta function therefore I am not recognized")
def user_func4():
    print("I am registered through an instance function therefore I am not recognized")
def user_func5():
    print("I am registered through a static function therefore I am not recognized")
```

And a little test:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = ClassTest()
    a.testFunc["user_func"] = user_func
    a.testFunc["user_func"]()
    a.testFunc["user_func2"] = eval("user_func2")
    a.testFunc["user_func2"]()

    ClassTest.testFunc["user_func"] = user_func
    ClassTest.testFunc["user_func"]()
    ClassTest.testFunc["user_func2"] = eval("user_func2")
    ClassTest.testFunc["user_func2"]()

    a.registerClassFunc("user_func5")  # does not work on import
    a.testFunc["user_func5"]()
    ClassTest.registerClassFuncFromStatic("user_func3") # does not work on import
    ClassTest.testFunc["user_func3"]()
    ClassTest.registerClassFuncOnClass("user_func4") # does not work on import
    ClassTest.testFunc["user_func4"]()
```

All this works **provided** all these elements are in the same file. As soon as the functionality is split up in 2 files and a main file:

```
from ClassTest import ClassTest
from UserFunctions import user_func,user_func2, user_func3, user_func4, user_func5
if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = ClassTest()
    a.testFunc["user_func"] = user_func
    ...
```

Only the first two keep working (setting the function directly), the others - using a function to do the same thing - give a `NameError` on all the `eval` calls. For instance: `NameError: name 'user_func5' is not defined`.

What is the logic here for the loss of scope when using the methods versus directly setting the functions? And can I get it to work using imports from other packages so I can place any function in the class with a method rather than directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[There's a live version of fix #1 from this answer online that you can try out for yourself](https://repl.it/@telamonian/ClassTestrefactoroutevalrefactorininspecthacks)

## The problem

You're right that the reason this doesn't work is due to scoping issues. You can figure out what's going on by scrutinizing the [docs for `eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval):

> eval(expression, globals=None, locals=None)
>
> ...If both dictionaries [ie globals and locals] are omitted, the expression is executed in the environment where eval() is called.

Thus, it is reasonable to assume that the issue you're having is down to the contents of `globals` and `locals` in the context (ie within the definition (and possibly separate module) of `ClassTest`) in which `eval` is getting called. Since the context in which `eval` is getting called is not, in general, the context in which you have defined and/or imported `user_func, user_func2....`, these functions are undefined as far as `eval` is concerned. This line of thinking is backed up by the [docs for `globals`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals):

> globals()
>
> ...This is always the dictionary of the current module (inside a function or method, this is the module where it is defined, not the module from which it is called).

## The fix

You have a few different options for how you can go about fixing this code. All of them are going to involve passing `locals` from the context in which you call, eg, `ClassTest.registerClassFunc` to the context in which that method is defined. Additionally, you should take the opportunity to factor out the use of `eval` from your code (its use is considered bad practice, it's a [massive security hole](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37081082/425458), yadda yadda yadda). Given that `locals` is the dict of a scope in which `user_func` is defined, you can always just do:

```
locals['user_func']
```

instead of:

```
eval('user_func')
```

### fix #1

[Link to live version of this fix](https://repl.it/@telamonian/ClassTestrefactoroutevalrefactorininspecthacks)

This'll be the easiest fix to implement, since it only requires a few tweaks to the definitions of the methods of `ClassTest` (and no changes to any method signatures). It relies on the fact that it is possible to use the `inspect` package within a function to directly grab the `locals` of the calling context:

```
import inspect

def dictsGet(s, *ds):
    for d in ds:
        if s in d:
            return d[s]
    # if s is not found in any of the dicts d, treat it as an undefined symbol
    raise NameError("name %s is not defined" % s)

class ClassTest():
    testFunc = {}
    def registerClassFunc(self, funcName):
        _frame = inspect.currentframe()
        try:
            _locals = _frame.f_back.f_locals
        finally:
            del _frame

        ClassTest.testFunc[funcName] = dictsGet(funcName, _locals, locals(), globals())

    @classmethod
    def registerClassFuncOnClass(cls, funcName):
        _frame = inspect.currentframe()
        try:
            _locals = _frame.f_back.f_locals
        finally:
            del _frame

        cls.testFunc[funcName] = dictsGet(funcName, _locals, locals(), globals())

    @staticmethod
    def registerClassFuncFromStatic(funcName):
        _frame = inspect.currentframe()
        try:
            _locals = _frame.f_back.f_locals
        finally:
            del _frame

        ClassTest.testFunc[funcName] = dictsGet(funcName, _locals, locals(), globals())
```

If you use the above given definition of `ClassTest`, the import test you cooked up will now function as expected.

#### Pros

- Provides exactly the originally intended functionality.
- Involves no changes to function signatures.

#### Cons

- Calling `inspect.currentframe()` can cause a dip in performance, so you may not be able to use this fix if you're planning on calling the methods of `ClassTest` a million times a second.
- `inspect.currentframe()` is only guaranteed to work on CPython. [Mileage may vary when running this code with other implementations of Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9938980/inspect-currentframe-may-not-work-under-some-implementations).

### fix #2

Fix #2 is basically the same as fix #1, except that in this version you explicitly pass `locals` into the methods of `ClassTest` at the point of call. For example, under this fix the definition of `ClassTest.registerClassFunc` would be:

```
def registerClassFunc(self, funcName, _locals):
        ClassTest.testFunc[funcName] = dictsGet(funcName, _locals, locals(), globals())
```

and you would call it in your code like this:

```
a = ClassTest()
a.registerClassFunc("user_func5", locals())
```

#### Pros

- Doesn't rely on `inspect.currentframe()`, and so is probably more performant/portable than fix #1.

#### Cons

- You have to modify method signatures, so you'll also have to change any existing code that uses those methods.
- You'll have to add the `locals()` boilerplate to every invocation of every `ClassTest` method from here on.