# what alternative of inspect.currentframe() can be for ironpython?

Tags: ironpython

I have a problem.
Command `inspect.currentframe()` return me NoneType from ironpython.

I find here https://stackoverflow.com/a/9939549/2554349 that IronPython cant tell me the line number of code (using `inspect.currentframe()`).

What alternative of `inspect.currentframe()` can be for ironpython? I just want to get line number of ironpython code and line number of ironpython def.

Thanks.